# C++ return a pointer to a class

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have a class.

I need to create a function that returns a pointer to a member of this class.

My class looks like this:

```
class clsNode
{
private:
    wstring m_grapheme;
    vector <clsNode*> m_Daughters;
public:
    clsNode *getNextNode(const udtCharVec &u);
};
```

I tried the following:

```
clsNode *clsNode::getNextNode(udtCharVec &u)
{

    if (u.Grapheme == m_grapheme)
    {
        return *m_Daughters[0];
    }
    else
    {
        return *m_Daughters[1];
    }
}
```

The compiler tells me "error c2511: clsNode:getNextNode(udtCharVec &): Overloaded member function not found in clsNode."

Can somebody tell me where I made a mistake?
Thank you!

Comment: the signature in class is with a const argument, your implementation without.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you meant:

```
return m_Daughters[0];
//    ^
```

because `m_Daughters[0]` is of type `clsNode*` and `*m_Daughters[0]` would be of type `clsNode` which would mismatch the return type.

Also your function signature is different in the definition and implementation:

```
clsNode *getNextNode(const udtCharVec &u)
//                   ^^^^^
clsNode *clsNode::getNextNode(udtCharVec &u)
```

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to be able to return one of the m_Daughters. I don't want to edit it, I only need read it. I hope I could explain it well. Do you think my way of storing and retrieving it is okay or would you do it differently?

Comment: @user2421725, it really depends by what those pointers actually mean. Why can't you store them as `clsNode` directly? Why do you need of dynamic memory allocation?

Answer (score 2):

You have several mistakes here. First you have declaration

```
clsNode *getNextNode(const udtCharVec &u);
```

which means that the function takes its argument by reference to const, whereas when you define the function you have this

```
clsNode *clsNode::getNextNode(udtCharVec &u)
```

The signatures are different (notice the lack of const in the second one).

The second problem is in the return statements:

```
return *m_Daughters[0];
```

type of the returned value is a reference, not a pointer (the * there dereferences the pointer that you get from the vector). To fix this, do this:

```
return m_Daughters[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

The method signature in the class declaration is:
    clsNode *getNextNode(const udtCharVec &u);

but the implementation below is:
    clsNode *clsNode::getNextNode(udtCharVec &u)

Note the "const" in the declaration.  The compiler is telling you it can't find the declaration for the one you implemented at the bottom